# I am using the ... in R for control variables in a function I am making, how do I convert the control variables to a list?

Tags: r, list, function, gwr

I have this function which does a geographically weighted regression, I have my shape-file, `x` for x variable and `y` for y variable, the `...` is for the control variables. For example I want to call a regression first but with multiple control variables - how would I do that?

```
GWR.function <- function(shape1, x, y, ...) {
    model <- lm(shape1[[x]] ~ shape1[[y]] + shape1[[...]])
    return(summary(model))
}
```

I assume that it requires the use of a list but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: just clarifying, `x`, `y`, and the elements of `...` are supposed to be strings?

Answer (score 2):

In general `do.call()` is how you introduce a list as the arguments to a function. Here I combined `y` with `...` and passed the resulting `character` vector to `reformulate`. If you want to work with individual elements of `...`, `list(...)` will convert it to a "regular" list.

```r
## set up example
dd <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))

GWR.function <- function(shape1, x, y, ...) {
    predvars <- do.call("c",c(list(y),...))
    form <- reformulate(predvars, response=x)
    model <- lm(form, data=shape1)
    return(summary(model))
}
GWR.function(dd, "x","y","z")
```

You could redefine your function as `function(shape1, x, ...)` to simplify the code slightly (then `predvars <- do.call("c", ...)`)